# Table of Contents navigation in Xcode (using Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to create a clickable Table of Contents, whereby the chapters of a book appear when you click on the name of the book, as in the screen shots below.

I've tried Googling this under the search terms 'nested menus in xcode swift', 'table of contents navigation in xcode swift' 'tableview navigation xcode' etc but I can't find what I am looking for.

Can anyone tell me what terms I should be Googling in order to find a tutorial on this topic?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a solution or library which you can use directly?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution

Comment: If you know of a library, that would also be good...